# How does async code really work under the hood in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've spent the last two weeks learning about the following:
setImmediate, process.nextTick, setTimeout, promises, callbacks, libuv, the event loop, job/microtask queue, event loop queue, call stacks, etc.

I've truly gone down a rabbit hole that I can't escape and while I find myself a lot more informed, I'm still have trouble grasping async code in JavaScript.

I'd like to take the following basic scenario and understand how I might implement it async.:

```js
// does nothing; here to simulate functionality below
var data = new Array(10000000);

const displayTime = desc => {
  var time = new Date();
  console.log(
    ("0" + time.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
    ("0" + time.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
    ("0" + time.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + " " + desc
  );
}

displayTime('starting ...');

// --- async/await (a promise):

const processData = async(data) => {
  let dataLen = data.length;
  let processedData = [];
  //console.time('#1');
  for (let ctr = 0; ctr < dataLen; ctr++) {
    // something happens here; simulating a long task using a for-loop;
    // for purposes of this question, let's just assume it's necessary to do this
    processedData.push(ctr / 33 * 383739722);
  }
  //console.timeEnd('#1');
  return processedData;
}

(async() => {
  result = await processData(data);
  // console.log(result);
  displayTime('#1 completed ...');
})();

// --- promise:
const processData2 = data => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let dataLen = data.length;
    let processedData = [];
    //console.time('#2');
    for (let ctr = 0; ctr < dataLen; ctr++) {
      processedData.push(ctr / 33 * 383739722);
    }
    //console.timeEnd('#2');
    resolve(processedData)
  });
}

processData2(data).then(data => {
  // console.log(data);
  displayTime('#2 completed ...');
});

displayTime('end of program ...');
```

Output is:

```
18:09:48 starting ...
18:09:52 end of program ...
18:09:52 #1 completed ...
18:09:52 #2 completed ...
```

As you can see from the output, "end of program ..." wasn't echoed to the screen until after the two long running processes completed (see time).

Why?

How could I have run these two tasks (which both use promises) in the background so that they don't block the event loop and my "end of program ..." string echo immediately?

Comment: Declaring a function `async` doesn't make it run asynchronously. It's just syntactic sugar for returning a promise, which makes it easier to use *if* it executes asynchronous code, and allows it to use `await` internally to call other async functions.

Comment: How would I make it run async? Is this possible? Or would I have to port my code to another language that supported threads?

Comment: Call something like `setTimeout`.

Comment: setTimeout would just delay execution of the code until after the event loop; it wouldn't make it async either.

Comment: `setTimeout` executes its callback function asynchronously.

Comment: There are quite a few articles and tutorials on getting started with async code in JavaScript that suggest doing a setTimeout(callback, 0). Well, now you know what the Event Loop does and how setTimeout works: calling setTimeout with 0 as a second argument just defers the callback until the Call Stack is clear. --https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5

Comment: When I run your code snippet, I just get the `starting` message and an error screen. Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: Loop was too big for browser; I removed two zeros and now it works but time is off.

Comment: @Barmar It seems like Gary has some set of synchronous processing that he is trying to make execute asynchronously, i.e. in a non-blocking manner. In this case the only option is worker threads.

Comment: Thank you Klaycon ... I've discovered after weeks of research on the event loop (generally) that most folks don't understand async. in JavaScript. It's a tough subject and I'm struggling w/it myself, but I think this thread has helped me understand that my code will always be sync. unless I use a worker thread or move the processing to a lib. that I either create myself or leverage.

Comment: Right. Unless you use worker threads, JavaScript is single-threaded. Running a function asynchronously just defers starting it until code returns to the event loop, but once a function starts it runs to completion. So if you have a long-running function, it will block the UI even if run asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Barmar Nitpick: "*Running a function asynchronously …*" sounds like "calling an `async function`. To clarify: "*Scheduling a function to be executed asynchronously just defers…*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript runs in a single thread, always. If you have heavy synchronous processing load, simply dropping that synchronous load in an async context is not sufficient: the execution may be delayed, but when it does come time for the function to execute, all code within still executes synchronously.

You have effectively two options:

1. Spawn a worker thread using node.js's [`cluster` api](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) and have the worker thread execute the synchronous processing
2. Manually delay your synchronous processing at certain points by using something like [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args) and separating the processing into discrete chunks which can be processed one at a time.

For your research, you may be interested to read that node.js itself [uses worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_threadpool_usage) for filesystem operations. Network operations I believe are handled by polling. In both cases all processing load happens out of the main node.js process (either on another thread or another computer). If your goal is to have synchronous processing load be non-blocking you should do the same.

I also found this excellent guide in the node.js docs which cover essentially what I describe above but using better terminology and more detail: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/#complex-calculations-without-blocking-the-event-loop

Comment: So just to wrap up my understanding of this subject: I should only use promises w/code that is indeed async. unless my purpose is to defer?

Comment: Yes and no. You can (and this is often done) chain promises and execute some parts synchronously.

Comment: `async function x() { return 1; }` is the same as writing `function x() { return Promise.resolve(1); }`

Comment: @Gary More or less. Promises are great when using an API (native or library) which uses them, or you can sometimes make them to wrap old callback style APIs. Most often this is only useful for things involving network requests and filesystem operations. If you need to handle heavy processing load, threads are the way to go.